# Cannot link project with library and executable using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am a newbie in cmake. I don't understand how my CMakeLists should look like.

```
#include "StackVector.h"
#include "profile.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  {
    StackVector<int, 10> sV;

  }
}
```

This is my main.cpp, I also have some implementation of StackVector (StackVector.cpp, StackVector.h). My CMakeLists.txt look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(StackVector)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_library(StackVector SHARED StackVector.cpp)
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app StackVector)
```

Finally, after I build my project I get an error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "StackVector<int, 10ul>::StackVector()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: "I also have some implementation of StackVector" - Please, **show that implementation**. Specifically the part which **defines** (implements) the method, which is noted in the error message as "undefined".

Comment: Might you need to *include* the header file during compilation? Try adding `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})` to your CMake code.

Comment: What does `StackVector.h` look like? Your CMake file is fine